# Continuous riemann integral

Tags: riemann-integration

Let $f: [-1, 1] \to \mathbb R$ be a continuous function such $f(x) \ge 0$ for every $x \in [-1, 1]$ and $f(0)=1$ Show that the lower $\int_{-1}^1f>0$.

This is about being continuous, am I correct?  But that's how far how I've gotten.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $f \ge 0$ we have $\int_{-1}^1f(x) dx \ge 0$. From $f(0)=1$ and the continuity of $f$ we get some $a \in (0,1)$ such that $f(x) \ge 1/2$ for all $x \in (-a,a)$. It follows that

$\int_{-1}^1f(x) dx  \ge \int_{-a}^a f(x) dx \ge \int_{-a}^a \frac{1}{2} dx =a>0$

Answer (score 0):

Another proof: Let $F(x)=\int_{-1}^xf(t) dt $ for $x \in [-1,1]$.

Suppose that $\int_{-1}^1f(x) dx = 0$. Since $f$ is continuous, $F$ is an antiderivative of $f$. Hence we have

1. $0=F(1)-F(-1)$

and

2. $F'=f \ge 0$.

Therefore $F$ is increasing, thus

$F(-1) \le F(x) \le F(1)$  for all $x \in [-1,1]$.

From 1. we see that $F$ is constant, hence $f(x)=0$ for all $x \in [-1,1]$, a contradiction.